# How can I switch focus in React.js between buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I open the page I want it to be focused n the start button, so I can press the g button to start a stopwatch. After I start it, I want the focus shifted to the stop button, which I can stop with the spacebar. I'm trying to use refs to make this happen, but struggling to figure it out.

```
import React, {useEffect, useReducer, useRef} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {

    // focus on start button before timer is started
    // once its started switch focus to stop button
    // redo

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {milliSecondsElapsed: 0};
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.textInput = React.createRef();

    }

    updateState(e) {
        this.setState({milliSecondsElapsed: e.target.milliSecondsElapsed })
    }

    keyPress = (e) => {
        // g button
        if (e.keyCode == 71) {
            handleStart();
        }
    }

    keyPress = (e) => {
        // spacebar
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            handleStop();
        }
    }

    handleStart = () => {
        this.setState({
            milliSecondsElapsed: (0)
        });
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                milliSecondsElapsed: (this.state.milliSecondsElapsed + 1)
            });
        }, 10)
    }

    handleStop = () => {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    render() {
        return (

            
            <div className="index">
                <input value = {this.state.milliSecondsElapsed} onChange = {this.updateState} ref="myInput"></input>
                <button onClick = {this.handleStart}>START</button>
                <button onClick = {this.handleStop}>STOP</button>
            </div>

        );
    }

}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Any chance you bind the keyboard events to the started independently from the button events? I mean by using onKey*

Comment: Start with the docs and assign your refs correctly: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs . right now your're setting ref to an arbitrary `"myInput"` string.